# SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import in React.js project linux OS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, windows, sass

I have a react.js project that another developer claims it works fine with his windows 10 OS. But for me when I tried to get the project up and running, I got this error message.

```
@import "styles/config";
```

> SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.   ╷ 1 │ @import
> "styles/config";   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ╵
> src/components/avatar/avatar.module.scss 1:9  root stylesheet

As far as I understand avatar.module.scss can't import the scss file.
This is the folder structure

[image]

And in the .env file it has a record

> SASS_PATH=./node_modules;./src

I assume this is the case. I think is not working in the Linux environment.
I am running React app in normal react script

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
```

And the sass version in the package.json is this

```
"sass": "1.32.8"
```

How do I fix this and get this project up and running? and also I can't adjust the import statement for something like this `@import "../../styles/config";` Because there are so many places and this code already works in the Windows environment.

Comment: styles/_config.scss with the underscore _

Answer (score -3):

Probably you need to add the underscore in the import:

@import "styles/_config.scss";